# React Router Получить props.match.params для элементов без категории

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как происходит передача данных для компонентов списка ? Как для карточки получить именно, те данные которые к ней относятся ? Вот [упрощённый пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/props-match-params-7nrsq?file=/src/GamePage.js)

```js
import { NavLink, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const GamePage = withRouter((props) => {
  const { games } = props;

  // const game = props.games.get(props.match.params.gameUrl);
  //  console.log("game = ", game);

  // TODO Переделать... тут всегда отдаеться первая запись а надо правильно
  const first = games[0];
  const gameData = {
    gameName: first.gameName,
    gameSeo: first.gameSeo,
    gameAdded: first.gameAdded
  };

  // const id = props.match.params.id;

  return (
    <div className="game_block">
      <h1 className="game_name">{gameData.gameName}</h1>
      <p className="game_description">{gameData.gameSeo}</p>
      <p className="game_gameAdded">{gameData.gameAdded}</p>
      <NavLink to="/">HOME</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
});

export default GamePage;
```

Как происходит матчинг именно нужных данных ? Почему в примерах всегда приводят матчинг по id параметру?(Если я правильно понял, то там же просто, этот параметр должен быть уникальным в приделах объекта)

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста на текущем примере, как нажимая скажем на ссылку basketball в компонент GamePage получать значения из state.js которые относятся к карточке баскетбол. Как реализовать get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал вам провести рефакторинг `Route` и использовать `gameId` в [url-params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <HomePage games={this.state.games} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/:gameId">
    <GamePage games={this.state.games} />
  </Route>
  <Route component={NoPageFound} />
</Switch>
```

Затем используйте [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), чтобы найти `currentGame`, как показано ниже:

```
const GamePage = withRouter((props) => {
  const { games, match } = props;
  const gameId = match.params.gameId;

  const currentGame = games.find((game) => String(game.id) === String(gameId));

  const gameData = {
    gameName: currentGame.gameName,
    gameSeo: currentGame.gameSeo,
    gameAdded: currentGame.gameAdded
  };

  return (
    <div className="game_block">
      <h1 className="game_name">{gameData.gameName}</h1>
      <p className="game_description">{gameData.gameSeo}</p>
      <p className="game_gameAdded">{gameData.gameAdded}</p>
      <NavLink to="/">HOME</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
});
```

**Редактировать:**

Если вы хотите использовать `gameUrl`:

**App.js:**

```
<Route exact path="/:gameUrl">
  <GamePage games={this.state.games} />
</Route>
```

и

**GamePage.js:**

```
// ..
const gameUrl = match.params.gameUrl;
const currentGame = games.find((game) => game.gameUrl === gameUrl + "/");
// ...
```

[image: Edit props-match-params]

Comment: можна узнать зачем вы заменили роут по имени игры, на роут по id игры ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Нет веской причины. Но "ID" вроде бы проще. Скажите, если вам это нужно с "gameName", я могу отредактировать свой ответ. Имя может быть продублировано, но идентификатор никогда не будет дублироваться. (если идентификатор взят из базы данных)

Comment: Только начинаю изучать Реакт, вопрос больше про SSR. Неужели боту или при продвижении страниц нету разницы будет ли ити на /id или на /football ?

Comment: `/football` лучше для [Поисковая оптимизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Отредактирую свой ответ.